# Is every quasipositive knot strongly quasipositive?

Tags: reference-request, knot-theory, gt.geometric-topology

A link is called **quasipositive** if it has a special braid diagram, namely a product of conjugates of the positive standard generators of the braid group. If this product only contains words of the form $\sigma_{i,j} = (\sigma_i \cdots \sigma_{j-2})\sigma_{j-1} ( \sigma_i \cdots \sigma_{j-2})^{-1}$ then we call the link **strongly quasipositive**. These notions were introduced by Rudolph.

> Is every quasipositive knot strongly quasipositive?

On pp.102 of Rudolph's [Quasipositivity and new knot invariants](http://www.mat.ucm.es/serv/revmat/vol2-1/vol2-1d.pdf), he gives an example of a quasipositive **link** (of 3 components) which is not strongly quasipositive. Is there an example of a **knot** which is quasipositive but not strongly quasipositive?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As pointed out by [Hedden](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0509499), [Livingston](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0311036) showed that strongly quasipositive knots have $g(K) = g_4(K) = \tau(K)$, where $g_4$ is the smooth slice genus and $\tau$ is the Ozsváth-Szabó concordance invariant, so this is an easy way to show that some quasipositive knots aren't strongly quasipositive.  [Baader](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0504594) gave a list of knots which are quasipositive but not positive up to 10 crossings, and among these the criterion $g = g_4$ is actually equivalent to strong quasipositivity, so for example $8_{20}$ (with $g=1$ but $g_4=0$) is quasipositive but not strongly quasipositive.